# Camera Calibration with openCV - cv2.getOptimalNewCameraMatrix results in zero roi

Tags: python, python-2.7, opencv, camera-calibration

This is my first post here on stackoverflow. Please sorry for my english and my knowledge in programming if they are somehow disturbing.

Well, I am trying to do camera calibration with opencv 2.4.9 in windows 8.1 operating system (ubuntu operating system doesn't resolve the problem.)

Problem: I am using the code below to calibrate my camera, but it seems that if the number of my sample images (with check board pattern) is more than 2, then the roi of *newcameramtx,roi=cv2.getOptimalNewCameraMatrix(mtx,dist,(w,h),1,(w,h))* result in [0,0,0,0]. How is the number of samples connected to that result? (earlier, prior of making some changes in this code, the maximum number of samples was 12).

By saying maximum number of samples I mean the images acquired from my camera with the chessboard pattern, were the roi doesn't give good result if the number exceeds the maximum number.

The corner detection works very well. You can find my sample images [here](http://goo.gl/5EVXht).

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
"""
Created on Fri May 16 15:23:00 2014

@author: kakarot
"""

import numpy as np
import cv2
#import os
#import time
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
LeftorRight = 'L'

numer = 12
chx = 6
chy = 9
chd = 25
# termination criteria
criteria = (cv2.TERM_CRITERIA_EPS + cv2.TERM_CRITERIA_MAX_ITER, numer, 0.001)

# prepare object points, like (0,0,0), (1,0,0), (2,0,0) ....,(6,5,0)
objp = np.zeros((chy*chx,3), np.float32)
objp[:,:2] = np.mgrid[0:chy,0:chx].T.reshape(-1,2)

# Arrays to store object points and image points from all the images.
objpoints = [] # 3d point in real world space, (x25mm)
imgpoints = [] # 2d points in image plane.

enum = 1

while(enum<=numer):
    img=cv2.imread('1280x720p/BestAsPerMatlab/calib_'+str(LeftorRight)+str(enum)+'.jpg')

    gray = cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    # Find the chess board corners
    ret, corners = cv2.findChessboardCorners(gray, (chy,chx),None)
    #cv2.imshow('Calibration',img)

    # If found, add object points, image points (after refining them)
    if  ret == True and enum <= numer:

        objpoints.append(objp*chd)


        cv2.cornerSubPix(gray,corners,(11,11),(-1,-1),criteria)
        imgpoints.append(corners)


        # Draw and display the corners
        cv2.drawChessboardCorners(img, (chy,chx),corners,ret)
        cv2.imshow('Calibration',img)
        cv2.imwrite('1280x720p/Chessboard/calibrated_L{0}.jpg'.format(enum),img)
        print enum

        #time.sleep(2)
        if enum == numer:
            ret, mtx, dist, rvecs, tvecs = cv2.calibrateCamera(objpoints, imgpoints, gray.shape[::-1],None,None)

            img = cv2.imread('1280x720p/BestAsPerMatlab/calib_'+str(LeftorRight)+'7.jpg')
            gray = cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_RGB2GRAY)
            h,  w = img.shape[:2]           #a (1 to see the whole picture)
            newcameramtx, roi=cv2.getOptimalNewCameraMatrix(mtx,dist,(w,h),1,(w,h))
            if (np.size(roi) == 4 and np.mean(roi) != 0):
                # undistort
                mapx,mapy = cv2.initUndistortRectifyMap(mtx,dist,None,newcameramtx,(w,h),5)
                dst = cv2.remap(img,mapx,mapy,cv2.INTER_LINEAR)

                # crop the image
                x,y,w,h = roi
                dst = dst[y:y+h, x:x+w]
                dst = cv2.cvtColor(dst,cv2.COLOR_RGB2BGR)
                plt.imshow(dst)
                #cv2.imwrite('result.jpg',dst)
                #np.savetxt('mtxL.txt',mtx)
                #np.savetxt('distL.txt',dist)
            else:
                np.disp('Something Went Wrong')
        enum += 1
'''
    k = cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF
    if k == 27:
        break
'''
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

**EDIT:** I am using two cheap usb cameras. I figured out that the sample set of one of the cameras is ok, and i can use more than 19 samples without problem. But when using the calibrating samples of the other camera the maximum number of sample images is 2. (if I make another set of samples the number will vary). In conclusion it seems that there is something going on with the calibrating matrixes that produce. But it is weird though.

Finally I am using fisheye cameras, believing that cutting enough pixels around the end of each capture I would simulate a normal camera... maybe this is what is causing me the trouble!

Comment: You should really find a better title for your question

Comment: You are totally right. I forgot it, thank you.

Comment: Di you manage to make it work for a fisheye camera? In my case it looks like the icvGetRectangles function in the c++ code called inside getOptimalNewCameraMatrix can't deal with large FOV camera. It can't find the inner and outer rectangle.

Answer (score 1):

You should change dist to

```
dist = np.array([-0.13615181, 0.53005398, 0, 0, 0]) # no translation
```

and then make call to

```
newcameramtx, roi=cv2.getOptimalNewCameraMatrix(mtx,dist,(w,h),1,(w,h))
```

It worked for me.

Comment: Which camera (FOV) are you using?

Comment: I am using a simple webcam of hp

Comment: the last argument in the dist array does not need to be 0, only array index 2 and 3 control the translation, the others are radial distortion parameters.

Comment: @Sam, how did you calculate them?